# static_assert cause compilation errors while included in c file with linux GNU compilation

Tags: c++, c, embedded-linux, static-assert

I have static assert that validates structures size on compilation time in order to avoid padding issues,
and make sure all my structures are aligned to 4.
Some of my code is cpp files and some is c code.
While in cpp files compilation works fine, in c file I got compilation error.
In my H file I defined something like that

```
//Macro definition
#define TEST_STUCRTURE_SIZE(structToTest, sizeToCompare)\
    static_assert(sizeof(structToTest) == sizeToCompare, "Structure size error");
    
//Structure definition in H file 
typedef struct SExampleStruct   
{
    int field1;
    int field2;
}SExampleStruct;

TEST_STUCRTURE_SIZE(SExampleStruct, 8)
```

While including this H file in cpp files everything works fine
While including this H in c files I get compilation error :
**"error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'sizeof'**

Comment: You may wanna clean up the spelling of `STUCRTURE` :)

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't have `static_assert` (before C23), I think what you need is `_Static_assert`. You can see it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Static_assert).

Your macro can be changed to :

```cpp
//Macro definition
#if defined(__cplusplus)
#define TEST_STUCRTURE_SIZE(structToTest, sizeToCompare)\
    static_assert(sizeof(structToTest) == sizeToCompare, "Structure size error");
#else
#define TEST_STUCRTURE_SIZE(structToTest, sizeToCompare)\
    _Static_assert(sizeof(structToTest) == sizeToCompare, "Structure size error");
#endif
```

Comment: It would be simpler to `#include <assert.h>`

Comment: Indeed. Most of these C++ inspired features in C11 are designed so that you only need to include one header and then regardless of if compiled as C or C++, it will work. For example C++ `assert.h` will not define the `static_assert` macro, so including it from the C++ source is harmless.